# How to test is hardware ssd-cache work?

Tags: cache, ssd, hardware-raid, adaptec, iops

We have server with hardware raid controller (Adaptec ASR71605Q).
It has 10 sas HDD, 2 SSD for cache and 1gb onboard cache ram.

On server installed ESXi. On ESXi I'm start Linux, create 2Tb disk for tests.
And now i need to test and ensure, that ssd-cache is really work.
Adaptec utilities installed to ESXi (arcconf), but it's not clear is ssd-cache works or not.

I use fio to test iops with "direct=1" mode (that should work thru all caches directly with physical disks), and I get something around 1800 iops on 4k random writes with queue=32, that seems real 10 HDD speed.

Now i need perform some tests, that show, that ssd is work, but with all configuration I still get around 1800-2000 random iops. 
Which test on Linux can get me proof of ssd-caching?

Comment: Have you given it time to actually cache some HDD data yet? it's not immediate usually, it's based on commonly-read/written sectors

Comment: I try to do some writes, that should use cache, for example: create 50gb files with zeroes, then read this file.
And in the end write and read speed is the same, as in configuration without ssd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RAID controller is able to gather statistics that show how the cache is used. You will need the `arcconf` command for this.

The following command should give you plenty of numbers that show how the cache is used:

```
arcconf GETLOGS 1 STATS tabular
```

Maybe you need to enable the statistics using the following command:

```
arcconf SETSTATSDATACOLLECTION 1 Enable
```